# Reindexing products twices

Tags: magento-1.9

I have started reindexing process of products  using this command

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

and it is still stuck on this step

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
```

If I interrupt the process and repeat the reindexing process It doesn't affect the project (It is a high scale project)
Thanks in advance

Comment: how long is it taking? reindexing the catalog urls can take a long time, be patient :)

Comment: well there is an error with reindexing items with ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0):

If there are no entries in the error logs just let it run until it ends. Open screen in your terminal and start the indexer.